# Pass a property parameter to the Vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm using Vue+Laravel, I want to make a modal window with 2 tabs. I have two buttons, each button must open certain connected tab.
Buttons are places in `blade` template:

```
<button @click="openModal('login')">
<button @click="openModal('register')">

//Vue component also is placed in blade template
<auth-component :show="showModal" :active_tab="activeTab" @close="showModal = false"></auth-component>
```

`/resources/assets/js/app.js`:
I want to pass `openModal()` ***parameter*** to a component...

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        showModal: false,
        activeTab: '',
    },
    methods: {
        openModal(tab) {
            this.activeTab = tab;
            this.showModal = true;
        }
    },
});
```

... and use that ***parameter*** as Vue `prop` to set certain [bootstrap-tab](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/) as active inside Vue-component:

`AuthComponent.vue`:

```
<div class="modal-mask" @click="close" v-show="show">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container" @click.stop>
            <b-card no-body>
                <b-tabs card>
                    <b-tab title="Login" :active="active_tab === login">
                    <b-tab title="Register" :active="active_tab === register">
                </b-tabs>
            </b-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
props: ['show', 'active_tab'],
```

But my current code does not work. There are no console errors. Just first tab (login) is always active after modal is opened.

---

**UPDATE**: I moved to

```
<b-tab title="Login" :active="active_tab === login">
<b-tab title="Register" :active="active_tab === register">
```

and I see that in Vue console needed tab get `active: true` property. But while `active: true` Register tab is anyway `display: none`. So I guess setting `active` property as `true` isn't enough to actually make tab content visible.

[JSFiddle component code](https://jsfiddle.net/9uhafq2p/1/)

Comment: If there are any ways to debug if my `active_tab` prop has needed value after button is clicked, please tell me. I used `console.log()` to check `activeTab` inside `app.js` and it was ok.

Comment: `active_tab` will be a string so it should be `:active="active_tab === 'login'"`

Comment: @Matt I've tried it. I checked in Vue devtools that needed tab get `active` parameter. But it's class doesn't change to `active show`

Comment: Also a quick way to debug props is log out from a computed. e.g. `computed: { activeTabDebug() { console.log(this.active_tab); } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try wrapping them in `<b-tabs v-model="tabIndex"></b-tabs>` and then have a computed method that determines the index based off the prop.

### EDIT

```
computed: {
  tabIndex: {
    get: function() {
      if (this.activeTab === 'register') {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      return newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I checked Vue devtools and noticed that `active` property is etting correctly. But setting `active` property isn't enough to make tab active (active in last meaning is when tab conent is shown to user) as seems to me. I hope I explained well...

Comment: @DoIGetAnything are you wrapping them in <b-tabs>? Can you update the example with a little more of the wrapping code?

Comment: I've added [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9uhafq2p/1/). Yes, I'm warapping in `<b-tabs>`

Comment: @DoIGetAnything looking in the vue bootstrap library looks like the tabs component handles setting the active tab on click. So the approach of using a computed to set the tabIndex is probably best for handling programmatic tab switching.

Comment: I did like this: `computed: {
            tabIndex() {
                if (this.active_tab === 'login') {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        },` (need to use `tabIndex` as func). But I get console error `Computed property "tabIndex" was assigned to but it has no setter.`

Comment: I did `computed: {
            tabIndex: {
                get() {
                    if (this.active_tab === 'login')
                    {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                },
                set() {
                    return;
                }
            }
        },` and there were no errors. I guess it's ok to leave `return` in `set()`...

Comment: @DoIGetAnything makes sense the v-tabs model will try setting a value to it on clicks. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `openModal.bind(undefined,'login')` so you return a function with the bound params instead of invoking that function.

Also, the tabs component is set with the v-model attribute. It uses numeric indexes to set the active tab.

Maybe make a lookup object to simplify things:
`const tab_map = { login: 0, register: 1 }`

Then you can setup `openModal.bind(undefined, tab_map.login)`

For the v-model setup on tabs, check this example out: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/#external-controls